# How do i fix left click mouse behavior for Logitech M720 Bluetooth mouse?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, mouse

I'm seeing the following symptoms on OS X Sierra:

After a duration of time, my Logitech M720 Triathlon Mouse will register all left clicks as a left-ctrl click. This results in web links being downloaded instead of opened - etc etc.

Turning off the mouse does nothing.

Turning off Bluetooth seems to reset to default behavior.

How do i determine whats causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally experience this behavior with my G700s. I think it's a problem with the Logitech driver/utility (if you happen to use it). I suggest you update to the [latest version](https://download01.logi.com/web/ftp/pub/techsupport/options/Options_6.62.200.zip); it was released just a few weeks ago.

Now that I think of it, I haven't had that problem in quite some time, now…

Comment: Im running latest

Answer (score 1):

This is a work around.

Turning off bluetooth, and turning it back on fixes the issue. The challenge was that i have an external mouse and keyboard that use bluetooth to connect.

Turning off bluetooth left me unable to turn bluetooth back on.

To do a full cycle reboot of bluetooth, i did the following.

Install http://www.frederikseiffert.de/blueutil/

```
$ brew install blueutil
$ blueutil power 0 && sleep 10 && blueutil power 1
```

This turns off the bluetooth radio, waits 10 seconds, and turns the radio back on. Upon bluetooth radio restart, the symptoms are fixed.